# Keydown Event with "Ctrl, Shift or Alt" does not trigger on Windows

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I would like to know when a user is pressing down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during mousemove.

The problem is that Windows doesn't trigger keydown event when pressing down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Instead, the event is triggered on releasing the key. On Mac everything is working as expected, however (keydown is triggered when you press down the key)

About the same problem with mouse move events. The event.shiftKey will only be true after you've held down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and triggered a mousedown...

Are there any workarounds for this? Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ecz0deqw/4/

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    addText('Key pressed: ' + e.key) 
};
document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    if(e.shiftKey)
        addText('ShiftMove');
   else {
       addText('NoShift')
   }
} 
function addText(text) {
    var newP = document.createElement("p"); 
    newP.innerText = text;
    document.body.insertBefore(newP,document.body.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Thanks / Eric

Comment: Try adding the events on `document.body` instead of `document`, and use `addEventListener()` to do so

Comment: According to the [`keydown` spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keydown), and the [spec regarding "modifier keys"](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#keys-modifiers), the `keydown` event should be raised.

Comment: Thanks for reaching back to me! No difference, the events of those keys still triggers on "keyup" rather than "keydown" on windows. https://jsfiddle.net/ecz0deqw/7/

Comment: I just tried your code on my Windows box and it's behaving as expected. Event is triggered on key down. Something must be different on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Windows machine a VM? Parallels (at least) does funny stuff with the modifier keys.

Under `Actions` > `Configure` go to the `Mouse & Keyboard` tab. Next to the `Keyboard` label, choose `Optimize for games`.

Underneath that option Parallels states: "When the keyboard is optimized for games, modifier keys become more responsive."

Comment: Thanks a lot, now the event is triggered on keydown. Shiftdown still need to happen BEFORE a mouseDown event for me to detect it it seems (genuine windows installation)

Comment: OMG, I'm developing an Electron App which uses keydown + modifier keys. I was testing on Parallels and I was going crazy with this. Thank you!